Half point formatting in latex exam class
I managed to have the \half command return a decimal point instead of a fraction by using \renewcommand*\half{,5}. However I would like the output to be 0,5 when a question is only worth half a point. Is it possible to achieve this? If so how?
Thanks for your help!

Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at our starter guide to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Following Read character preceding a command you can try, with LuaLaTeX, to check if the character before the command \half is a digit:
\renewcommand{\half}
  {%
    \directlua%
      {
        local n=tex.nest[tex.nest.ptr].tail
        if (n.id ~= 29 or n.char < 48 or n.char > 57) % no digit 0-9 before
        then
            tex.print("0.5")
        else
            tex.print(".5")
        end
      }%
}

n.id is 29 for glyphs and n.char from 48 to 57 are the ten digits (ASCII code).
Full example:
\documentclass{exam}

\renewcommand{\half}
  {%
    \directlua%
      {
        local n=tex.nest[tex.nest.ptr].tail
        if (n.id ~= 29 or n.char < 48 or n.char > 57) % no digit 0-9 before
        then
            tex.print("0.5")
        else
            tex.print(".5")
        end
      }%
}
\begin{document}

\newcommand\one{1}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{*{7}{c}}
    \verb+\half+      &
    \verb+1\half+     &
    \verb+9\half+     &
    \verb+0\half+     &
    \verb+a\half+     &
    \verb+\quad\half+ &
    \verb+\one\half+
 \\
 \half                &
 1\half               &
 9\half               &
 0\half               &
 a\half               &
 \quad\half           &
 \one\half
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}


